# Adding a If Statement to a Function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

What I am trying to do now, is putting an if statement at the beginning.

What I want to do is if Cell L3 <> 6, then stop and provide error "Please fill out all fields".

Note: How do I get this pop-up (previously used msg.box) to appear in the centre of the screen?

If Cell L3 = 6 then run the below function

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getRange("PNG Sheet!A1:F1");
var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Project Codes");
destSheet.appendRow(source.getValues()[0]);
ss.getRange('J7:L8').activate();
ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
ss.getRange('J10:L11').activate();
ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
ss.getRange('J13:L14').activate();
ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

ss.toast('Your Project has been registered')
   }
```

Comment: You need to know the comparison operators:  Look at the information at MDN [Link to documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Math#Comparison_operators)

Comment: This really wasnt what im after, i dont need any buttons as i have those already. I just need to work out how to add the if statement to the above function, but thank you, that has given me some more information to look at.

Comment: Here is another link that explains comparison operators.  [Link Comparison Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Comment: thanks, but yeah its still not working for me.

Comment: It's good to explain in your question what you have tried and what is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Let say that `cellL3Value` has the value of the cell L3. The following if statement will *[throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)* an error if `cellL3Value` is different than 6.

`if(cellL3Value !== 6) throw "Please fill out all fields";`

## Short explanation

Google Apps Script is based in JavaScript, so an [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) has the following form

`if(condition) statement1 [else statement2]`

A condition is any *[expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions)* that is considered to be *[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy)* or *[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Falsy)*.